# airflow Warning: Incorrect datetime value for column 'execution_date' at row 1

Tags: airflow

Have someone ever received this warning on airflow logs?

> sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:536: Warning: Incorrect datetime value: '2019-09-19 12:43:01.642075+00:00' for column 'execution_date' at row 1

I am getting this on every execution that I have on the airflow, at the beginning I thought that's not a real issue, but when I saw that all of the system execution time are ruined, here I started to worry, does anyone have experienced that and was managed to solve this?

The execution_datetime format on all of the runs on the system look like that now: **09-19T05:00:00+00:00**